# powershell function that prints letter grade with a range

Tags: powershell

so far i got this need help writing this function:

```
   if (grades$Final[i] >=90) {
         "A"
      }
      else if (grades$Final[i] >=80){
         "B"
      }
      else if(grades$Final[i] >=70){
         "C"
      }
      else if(grades$Final[i] >=60){
         "D"
      }
      else {"F"}
      }
}
```

Comment: What seems to be the problem?

Answer (score 2):

Hello in this case i would suggest using a `switch` instead of a bunch of `If` statements

In powershell we use `-lt` (less than) `-gt` (Greater than) `-eq` (Equal) `-ge` (Greater or equal) `-le` (Less than or equal)

I noticed you are using `[i]` to call the index in an array i assume. 
In powershell you can pipe `|`. So You can take an array and pipe it to a function. You can create an array using `@()`.

```
@("Hello","World") | Foreach-object{
    "$_ TEST"
}
```

Output

```
Hello TEST
World TEST
```

So i bet you are wondering what `$_` is. Well When you pipe its the object that was piped so as in the example above since the array had 2 entries the first loop it equaled *Hello* and the second time it equaled *World*

So here is a function to get Int to Grade Letters. As you can see at bottom piping Ints into the function

```
function Get-LetterGrade(){
    param(
        [Parameter(Position=1, ValueFromPipeline=$true)]
        [int]$Grade
    )
    process{
        switch($Grade){
             {$_ -ge 90} { "A" } 
             {$_ -ge 80 -and $_ -lt 90} { "B" }
             {$_ -ge 70 -and $_ -lt 80} { "C" }
             {$_ -ge 60 -and $_ -lt 70} { "D" }
             {$_ -lt 60} { "F" }
        }
    }
}

90,80,70,60,50 | Get-LetterGrade
```

Output would be

```
A
B
C
D
F
```

Comment: how should i input the if request

Comment: if($request -eq 'Get-Letter-Grade') {

    [int]$numberCount = Read-Int 'How Many Letters'

    Get-Letter-Grade $numberCount

Comment: So u want people to enter there own grade? just want to make sure i have context

Comment: yes i do. if i input 80 i want it to print B

Comment: i put a example at bottom of that function `80 | Get-LetterGrade` would print *B*

Comment: Your function will throw exceptions if they pass bad types to it.  Might want to use `-as`

Comment: you used `()` after the function name. that is not needed ... and can be misleading. i would remove that. [*grin*] ///// as an aside, i think it wold be more clear if you tested for `-in $Range` in the switch instead of using `-ge` & `-lt`. ///// lastly, you used double quotes ... i would only use double quotes when needed - and they aint needed in this situation.

Comment: i have this function here fibonacci when i enter 55 it does the sequence to 55 instead of doing 55 sequence

Comment: function Get-Fibonacci ($n) {

    $current = 0 ; 
    $previous = 1; 
    while ($current -lt $n) { 
        $current; 
        $current,$previous 
        $current += $previous,$current

Answer (score 1):

In Powershell numeric comparison operators are a little different...

> is -gt
>   < is -lt
>   = is -ge

There is a ton (...ton) of documentation on comparison operators in Powershell, which you can get via Google.

"else if" would be "elseif". Your variable name is a little weird. In Powershell, we start variable names with a dollar sign, "$". It sort of looks like you have an array named "grades$Final". It's confusing. Stick to conventions on variable names; descriptive and adhering to naming rules.

If I had to re-write your logic, I'd use something like...

```
$grades = @(12, 78, 83, 92)

foreach ($grade in $grades) {
    if ($grade -ge 90) {
        write-output 'A'
    } elseif ($grade -lt 90 -and $grade -ge 80) {
        write-output 'B'
    } elseif ($grade -lt 80 -and $grade -ge 70) {
        write-output 'C'
    } elseif ($grade -lt 70 -and $grade -ge 60) {
        write-output 'D'
    } elseif ($grade -lt 60) {
        write-output 'F'
    }
}
```